# Hide tooltip in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How do I hide the highlighted tooltip in AmCharts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the chart cursor of the chart or set:

```
"chartCursor": false
```

To hide blue ballon you have to set this property of your graph object:

```
"showBalloon": false
```

Comment: Thanks, setting `chartCursor` to false (or in my case just removing it) did it.